# Multithreaded Contact sync

Tags: ios, multithreading, contacts, abrecordref

I am trying to speed up syncing contacts all the contacts on the device to my app. At the moment its blocking the main thread when syncing the contacts.

I added the individual contact setup in an NSInvocationOperation and adding that to a NSOperationQueue.

I know that you can only access the UI in the main thread. What can't you access in regards to Address book data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The address book framework is generally safe to use from a background thread but their are pitfalls. The important caveats are mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/BasicObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH3-SW1):

> **Important** Instances of ABAddressBookRef cannot be used by multiple threads. Each thread must make its own instance.

and

> **Important** Record objects cannot be passed across threads safely. Instead, you should pass the corresponding record identifier. See “Using Record Identifiers” for more information.

Note that just because `NSInvocationOperation` are on the same `NSOperationQueue` does not guarantee that they will be executed on the same thread.

Comment: OK, thanks for the response. I will give this a go and make sure that the ABAddressBookRef is only being used by its associated thread.